# c sharp programs do not have access to uwp libraries

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have installed windows visual studio 2019 build tools. I am able to compile and run C and C# programs although I know nothing about either, especially C so I make write some gibberish here. I am trying to develop some UWP related apps for my electron js project which is why I am here. You can see a screen shot of my build tools window here:

[image]

However in C#, whenever I attempt to import any UWP libraries, for example:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
```

I get an error about libraries not being found. It seems to be ok in C though.

```
#include <windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.h>
```

Is there any setup I have missed? I want to be able to use DataTransfer e.t.c. I am doing everything, compilation, e.t.c from the command line. 
Many Thanks.

Comment: What project type did you created.  Electron js project ?

Comment: I am tyring to write a c# program with uwp functionality and then bundle it into my electron project.

Comment: If you want to use c# library in your electron project, you need to create Windows Runtime component and calling it from JavaScript. Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/walkthrough-creating-a-simple-windows-runtime-component-and-calling-it-from-javascript).